# Printing two variables - only second one printed when run from script

Tags: string, shell, concatenation

I'm trying to print to sting1 and string2 with a space in between using shell script.
defined strings a,b and printing them using echo with a space in between. However, a is replaced by b as below.

```
a='30 Jan 2016 22:'
b='30 Jan 2016 23:'
echo $a $b
```

Output:

```
30 Jan 2016 23:
```

String1 is override by string2 to display. However, the same is working from command prompt as below:

```
$ a='30 Jan 2016 22:'
$ b='30 Jan 2016 23:'
$ echo $a $b
30 Jan 2016 22: 30 Jan 2016 23:
```

Why do these behaviors differ?

Comment: "StackSnippets" are for HTML, JavaScript, &c only. Use the `{}` button to format code in other languages.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in bash, zsh, or sh... which shell / version are you using?

Comment: @DanLowe, see my answer for reproduction steps. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely cause of this is DOS newlines in your text files. This means you have a CRLF at the end of each line, sending the cursor back to the beginning.

When interpreted by UNIX tools, for which a LF (`\n`) is the only character involved in a newline, the CR (`\r`) preceding it becomes part of the data.

That makes the *actual* behavior of your code this:

```
a='30 Jan 2016 22:'$'\r'
b='30 Jan 2016 23:'$'\r'
echo $a $b
```

...first printing `$a`, **then returning the cursor to the beginning of the line** and overwriting it with `$b`.

Comment: You are perfectly right. My dumb mistake..I forgot to convert my script in cygwin using dos2unix. Thanks